# How to deploy React Frontend + Node Backend on a production server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend, nodemailer

This is the first time that I’m working on the topic React Frontend with Node Backend.
I have now a litte problem and I’ve invested a lot of time locking for a solution but with no success.

I have developed a contact form with `react.js` and `antd` as design and input validation component in the frontend. For the backend part I use node `express`, `cors` and `axios` for executing web requests. As package manager I use `yarn`.

This contact form is located in a public GitHub repo: https://github.com/philippbck/react-nodemailer

Down below your can find my `package.json` with all used dependencies:

```
 {
  "name": "react-nodemailer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.19.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "espress": "^0.0.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.2.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This contact form works perfectly local on my computer, but now I want to deploy this to my production cloud server with CentOS7 and Apache Webserver. But my problem is how? With my understanding I create a production build for the react frontend part with `yarn run build` and put all files from the build folder inside the htdocs folder on my server. And for the backend file `app.js` located in the root directory of my project I’ve created a root folder on my server called `/apps`. And I started the node service manually with node app on the server.

When I open my website with the contact form and I click on the submit button, the following error occurs:

```
xhr.js:166 OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/send net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My question is how I can deploy my contact form on a production server to make it woking? I don’t want to use a serverless solutions for this case. Thank you very much!

**UPDATE:**

After changing the axios POST url from "localhost" to my production url "philipp-buck.de" now the the following error occurs:

```
OPTIONS https://philipp-buck.de:5000/send net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should response your html

```
   // in the beginning of app
    app.use(express.static('public'));

   // ...your code

    // serves frontend application
    app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html'), { root: __dirname }, err => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it doesn´t help. I have added your code and updated the github repo. My backend file `app.js` is located in `/apps`. Do I need to resolve the path from `/apps` the `index.html` in the `htdocs` folder?

Comment: The new Error Message is `xhr.js:166 OPTIONS https://philipp-buck.de:5000/send net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: I haven't seen ```const path = require('path')``` try to work with localhost more attempts = better results :)

Comment: also I don't know what is your built folder for frontend, maybe you should change public on dist/build dirs

Comment: and if you use vps/vds try to use daemon as somebody mentioned pm2 ```pm2 start app.js```

Answer (score 2):

Contactform.js has backend URL to hardcoded to . localhot:5000 [https://github.com/philippbck/react-nodemailer/blob/master/src/contactform.js#L45]

Your production frontend needs to point to production backend.

Comment: Thanks for help! I have changed localhost to my production url "philipp-buck.de". The new Error Message is `xhr.js:166 OPTIONS https://philipp-buck.de:5000/send net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

Answer (score 1):

You should depoy on Production by [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)

Are you enable `cors` at Back-end or use proxy at Front-end ?

Comment: I have enabled cors in the backend.

Comment: My config has the following headers:
`<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://philipp-buck.de"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
  </Directory>`

Comment: You must install `https` if request has contain `https`

In addition, you must turnoff firewall or open port .

Comment: https and valid ssl certificate is installed and configured. I have allowed port 5000 on the firewall with `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT` but I´m getting the error message `OPTIONS https://philipp-buck.de:5000/send net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` sending the contact form.

Comment: I have disabled the firewall completely but doesn´t help.